# Checking for Null values in cursor Column

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

How can I go about checking a null value in a particular column for set of rows returned from cursor

```
   CURSOR c_vej IS
    select stednavn,vejnavn,postnr from rki.vejmednavn where navn=vejnavn and postnr=postnr and         type='C';
 c_vej123 c_vej%ROWTYPE;  
 BEGIN

 OPEN c_vej;
 LOOP
 fetch c_vej into c_vej123;
```

stednavn,vejnavn,postnr is passed as Input to the procedure

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE "VEJ_CHECK" (


vejnavn   IN VARCHAR2,
postnr    IN number,
stednavn  IN out varchar2)
is



CURSOR c_vej IS
     select stednavn,vejnavn,postnr from rki.vejmednavn where navn=vejnavn and postnr=postnr and         type='C';
     c_vej123 c_vej%ROWTYPE;  
     BEGIN

     OPEN c_vej;
     LOOP
     fetch c_vej into c_vej123; 
     EXIT WHEN c_Vej%NOTFOUND;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- Employee: ');

    end loop;
    close C_VEJ;
```

END VEJ_CHECK;

{POSTNR,NAVN,STEDNAVN}={9240,Louisendalvej,Skørbæk},{9240,Louisendalvej,NULL},{9240,Louisendalvej,Ejdrup}

{POSTNR,NAVN,STEDNAVN}={7752,Hørstedvej,Harring},{7752,Hørstedvej,Sønderhå},{7752,Hørstedvej,   Hørsted}

columns name is Postnr,navn,stednavn and the corresponding values are listed after that

In this case c_vej(Cursor) may return rows in which stednavn is null or not null.If any row returned from this cursor has a value of stednavn as null.I want null to be returned from the procedure and if the cursor returns one or two rows with stednavn as not null in that case always the first row stednavn value  to be returned.

if the cursor returns the above 1st table in that case NULL should be returned from the procedure and if the cursor returns the second table in that case Harring should be returned.

How can I code the same in Oracle?

Comment: What do you mean, "return null?"  you are already fetching the "STEDNVAN" column value in your cursor.  The caller is free to do whatever they want with the cursor results. Also, "first row stednavn value to be returned?" There is no implicit ordering in a result set unless you have an ORDER BY clause.  So what is the "first" row if no ordering?

Comment: see the table which i have given in my edited post.I have listed out the output of Cursor

Comment: do u mean you're passing this cursor values into a procedure and then the procedure shud return null if there is any NULL value for STEDNAVN in the cursor results ? if yes, post the procedure as well.

Comment: @Shankar Please see the procedure which i have added above..I have written down this so far..